# Debug Sitecore JSS React while SSR

Tags: jss, react

How can I debug the JSS React application while using SSR, how to run the application with SSR in local machine with default npm commands?

Comment: Have you already tried any steps from the docs? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/configuring-and-debugging-the-node-js-rendering-engine.html